# LWC Visual Studio Code Dev Hub command

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, vs-code, dev-hub

[image]

I want to complete the Lightning Web Components Trail on Trailhead but I keep getting the error above.

- I installed the CLI and updated it to the pre-release version
- I installed Visual Studio Code
- I installed git and NodeJS
- I installed Salesforce extension pack and Lightning Web Components

And I keep getting this error.

Comment: Have you enabled the devhub in the devhub org ?

Comment: I did. And I don't think that that is the problem because login.salesforce.com does not open. I think it's an issue with CLI

Comment: What happens if you do force:auth:web:login directly from command line ?

Comment: I get the same error message as in the screenshot I posted. ( Thank you for your help by the way)

Comment: Which device are you on ? On Windows or Mac ox ?

Comment: Looks like something did not install properly .uninstall everything .Shut down and the reinstall

Comment: I am on Windows 10 OS . Actually uninstall everything several times. There is on thing that looks weird at every instalation is when I install the "Salesforce Extansion Pack" in VS code the SalesFoce CLI extansion takes forever to install. (I think the issue is related to that )

Comment: Do not install the VScode extension .You can work everything of command line so just install cli and see how it goes .

Comment: I only installed the CLI and the issue is happening

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/YSyxiaP

Comment: Raise a case with sfdc support .Seems like a problem specific to windows and for your os version .

Comment: In this last screenshot you can see that the CLI in installed properly https://imgur.com/a/Lq2q22P

Answer (score 6):

It turned out that my default browser was set to nothing.
It's a stupid thing but it drove me crazy.
I hope it helps if someone have the same issue.